# How to check if a var is in a table in nodeJS

Tags: node.js

I want to check if my var is in my array (a table). Here my code that doesn't work...

```
var color;
if(roll == green){
    color = "green";
}
else if(red.contains(roll)){
    color = "red";
}
else if(black.contains(roll)){
    color = "black";
}
```

Here my tables and my roll is sure between 0 and 14

```
var green = 0;
var red = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13];
var black = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14];
```

Comment: I believe this question was answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript

Comment: This looks like a perfect use of a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instead of an array since it's trivial to set if something is in a Set (that is its main purpose in life).

Comment: I believe you are looking for `Array.prototype.includes()`, there is not an `Array.prototype.contains()` method in JavaScript. Try `if(red.includes(roll)){...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the basic approach on the arrays is finding the index of the variable.  I'm assuming that you know `roll` will be a integer number, since  you don't show where that comes from.  If it might be a string (e.g. if it's coming from an HTML input element of some kind),  you'll need to use `parseInt()` to cast it.

```
if (roll === 0) {
  color = 'green';
} else if (red.indexOf(roll) !== -1) {
  color = 'red';
} else if (black.indexOf(roll) !== -1) {
  color = 'black';
}
```

Though to be honest, I'd consider structuring things differently depending on what my goals were.

Comment: Thanks a lot, my var "roll" is an integer its a random value between 0 à 14 :) thanks one more time have a nice night